# Achieving Excel like functionality in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling with achieving a requirement on a current system.

The system is intended to manage costs and project details and is currently provided through an Excel based solution. Each project consists of a number of weeks which are represented by columns, with a variety of data items presented on the rows. Project lengths are such that many projects have in excess of 150 columns. Columns and data items can be added dynamically, and the user wants to be able to navigate quickly around the grid using keyboard controls.

The business is moving from this unsupported Excel based solution to an application written in C# with a WPF front end, but the users still want a solution close to their existing spreadsheet.
I have initially tried to implement this using the Telerik WPF grid control that I have used elsewhere using dynamic/expando objects to hold the data and using the AutoGeneratingColumn event to create the controls for each of the columns. Initially the performance was acceptable but I had to turn off column and row virtualisation to enable the user to be able to tab through the fields, and this has resulted in a dramatic reduction in performance particularly when adding new rows and using filtering.

Is a grid control the right method to accomplish this requirement – could another third-party grid handle the dynamic column creation better - or is there an alternative design that could achieve both the performance and user interface requirements?

Comment: so you are telling me you want the application to be like excel so they stop using excel? srsly? god I hate those excel fetish people. For your problem, it will not work until you start rewriting those basic classes to suit your performance needs

Comment: I just can say, no one of wpf grids, standard or 3rd party will work as fast as excel works... Our team lost on this about 2 weeks, and no result. if you want to have performanced grid, use winform grid.Also you can use winform grid in wpf

Comment: Why not just use Excel? You said that the business is moving from the "unsupported" Excel solution. I don't see how your custom program written in C# would be more supported than a recognized file format.

Comment: Agreed.  One thing you might keep in mind, is that VSTO will let you do quite a bit of customization of an Office program.  Take the portions of your proposed solution, and put them in a custom task pane or wizard.  Excel has been developed for about 27 years, and it sounds like the functionality that it provides is great enough that you want to emulate it.  So go the easier (and more requirement matching route).  Stick with as much of the Excel functionality as you can, while introducing the custom functionality you need.

Comment: These particular screens are part of a general company wide system which is intended to replace a large number of different excel spreadsheets and ensure people do things in the correct way and we are trying to work towards a “single source of truth”  The problems with Excel sheets include, they aren't sharable with the rest of the business, often not backed up regularly, people have a habit of changing them without consulting anybody so you then end up with lots of subtlety difference versions of it.

Comment: I have dealt with these concerns in the past too, and ended up creating a customized toolset and a bunch of rules in Microsoft Publisher.  Rather than re-invent the canvas and all the drawing tools, I just locked down the save functionality, and put controls in place on who could perform what, and things they had to do to enable the ability to save.  Eventually I implemented a form of version control with the project to keep previous versions.